# how to display an icon or image in a uilabel or uitextview(uitextfield)

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uilabel

Can a `UILabel` display an icon or image? ?
I was making a chat application, which needs to show icon or image or custom image in a `UILabel` or `UITextField` so that an expression or pictures can be displayed. How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
textView.text = @"your text";
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: textView.frame];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"yourImage.png"];
[self.view addSubview: imgView];
[imgView addSubview: imgView];
```

Answer (score 1):

in iOS >= 7:

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

NSAttributedString *attachmentString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];

NSMutableAttributedString *myString= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]     initWithString:@"text bla bla bla"];
[myString appendAttributedString:attachmentString];

self.label.attributedText = myString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way for `UILabel`

```
labelname.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"]];
```

Or to set image as background to your `UITextView`

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame: window.frame];
    textView.text = @"text\n text\n text";
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: textView.frame];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myImage.jpg"];
    [textView addSubview: imgView];
    [textView sendSubviewToBack: imgView];
    [window addSubview: textView];
```

Comment: i want text and pictures together,  not  background .

Comment: +1 For you Heena,as for right answer...I was just looking the new questions,just saw your answer and gave +1 ...

Comment: i don't want to set its background image, i want to set an image(with text together,not single) in the UILabel or UITextView.. not background image..

Answer (score 0):

You can use *iphone emoji*. Read this [Iphone Emoji](http://inner.geek.nz/archives/2009/02/06/the-truth-about-iphone-emoji/)

Comment: i want to use custom icon or image.